# Is there any In-build method with Jquery to find validatable elements alone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find the elements from the form to validate. there is mixed type of elements. is there any way/method to get all elements which eligible to validate?

here is my try : but not works as expect.

```
var Validator = function (form) {

    this.form = form,
        this.elements = this.form.find(':input:not(button, submit)');

    this.validate = function () {

        $.each(this.elements, function(i,element){
            console.log(element);
        });

    }

}

var initiateValidate = function () {
    var form = $('form');
    var validator = new Validator(form);
    validator.validate();
}

initiateValidate();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/1/)

thanks in advance

Comment: What is not working *as expected*? And what is expected?

Comment: You should change `submit` to `[type="submit"]` to exclude inputs of type submit from your selection

Comment: I agree, But still is there a approach to get validatable inputs alone? like input, file, textarea, select, radio, checkboxes..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of my head, your best shot would be something like

```
$("input, select").not("[type=button],[type=submit]");
```

And then adding/removing the selectors as you see fit :)